# Adding additional fields to panels

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I'm working with Page Manager and Panels. I'm adding content (panels) to each custom page layout, and every panel has a title by default. Is there any way to add additional information, common to every panel, like a subtitle?

In other words, is there a way to add fields to the Panel entity?

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is, no. "the Panel entity", is not an entity at all, and doesn't even resemble an entity in any way. Fieldable panel panes however are entities, and are probably the closest you can get to an exact answer. You other alternative, if the additional data is common among a large number of panes (not panels), is to override the pane rendering with your own template, and preprocess the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that with [Fieldable Panels Panes (FPP)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes). Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... creates an entity that may be used in panel panes to create fieldable entity panes. These panes can be created either directly in the Panels UI or in a separate administrative UI and later added.
>
> Once added, they can appear in the "Add content" dialog to be easily reused. Since they are fieldable entities, they can contain any kind of data that field API can provide.
>
> Each entity supports revisions, and any revision can be made current without having to make a new revision.
>
> Access control is provided by the CTools access method, for both view and edit access.
>
> Bundles are supported and can be added via the UI or hook_entity_info_alter().
>
> A [Trello board](https://trello.com/b/nAMHVfvg/fieldable-panels-panes) is being used to help coordinate development.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of answer. I didn't quite succeed, although I suspect this may be the best way to go. I'm sorry, I come from a Wordpress background and still afraid to add additional modules if I can tinker a solution by myself.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct answer. For what I can see, this module creates "custom" empty panel panes. What I want is to add "custom" fields to existing panel panes. For example, adding a subtitle to a pane which contains a view, or a node.